# How is private key protected in Java JKS keystore file?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, java

I have been reading about JKS Java keystore, but didn´t find details about the format.

- The store password is just to verify the integrity of the file?
- How does the private keys are protected?

Comment: The way Java handles keys is obscure and frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> details about [JKS] format.

This is implemented by `sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore` 
[(source in mercurial)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java)
but is pretty simple and based on Java's `Data{Output,Input}Stream` conventions:
4-byte magic number, 4-byte version number, 4-byte count of entries; a variable number of entries each containing 4-byte type, length+(modified)UTF name, 8-byte timestamp, length+encoding+certcount for a privatekey, and type (in practice always `X.509`)+length+encoding for the/each certificate; and at the end hash of password plus preceding data for integrity check.

> The store password is just to verify the integrity of the file?

Yes. The JCA API, and the JKS format, allows each privatekey to be encrypted with a separate password, which can be different from the store password. `keytool` for example allows you to specify a key password, but *defaults* it to be the same as the store password. However, some *programs* cannot cope with differing key and store passwords; in particular, those using the default trustmanager and/or keymanager for SSL/TLS (and thus HTTPS) so in those cases the same password must be used for both store and key(s).

> How does the private keys are protected?

Each privatekey is PBE+hash using a 'proprietary' scheme in `sun.security.provider.KeyProtector` 
[(source in mercurial)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/KeyProtector.java) and formatted in the file as a PKCS#8 `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`.